Can't capture output on testing 'WriteFile' function call via JNA
I want to write a test which would confirm that my string is successfully printed to console via JNA using WriteFile function.
Specs:

Windows 11 Home, Version 22H2
Java 22
JNA 5.14.0

Kernel32.java
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    Kernel32 INSTANCE = Native.load("Kernel32", Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    Handle GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    boolean WriteFile(
        Handle hFile,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        int nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
        IntByReference lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        Overlapped lpOverlapped
    );
}

WriteFileFunctionCall.java:
public class WriteFileFunctionCall {
    public static void make() {
        final IntByReference written = new IntByReference();
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.WriteFile(
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetStdHandle(-11), "Hello, world", 12, written, null)
        );
    }
}

For capturing output I use @StdIo from Junit Pioneer
WriteFileTest.java:
import org.junitpioneer.jupiter.StdIo;
import org.junitpioneer.jupiter.StdOut;

class WriteFileTest {
    @Test
    @StdIo
    void prints(final StdOut output) {
        WriteFileFunctionCall.make();
        MatcherAssert.asssertThat(
            output.capturedString(),
            Matchers.equalTo("Hello, world")
        );
    }
}

When I run the test, I see "Hello, world" printed in console, so JNA function call works, but test fails because captured string in output is empty. What do I do wrong?

After a little research I found out how to solve this properly.
When you're writing to console using WriteFile with a handle got from GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) you interacts directly with the Windows console, skipping the Java System.out.
That's why capturing System.out using @StdIo does not work.
The only way to check if you write something to console via system call is to redirect standard output to file and read from the file then.
This is how you can do it

Include the JNA and JNA platform dependencies

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>{version-here}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
    <version>{version-here}</version>
</dependency>


Use Kernel32.java from Jna-platform as your system calls library

Make system call:


public class WriteFileFunctionCall {
    public static void make() {
        final IntByReference written = new IntByReference();
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.WriteFile(
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetStdHandle(Kernel32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), "Hello, world", 12, written, null)
        );
    }
}


Redirect standard output in the test:

class WriteFileTest {
    @Test
    void prints(@TempDir final Path temp) {
        // Create temporary file
        final File file = Files.createTempFile(
            temp, String.valueOf(action.hashCode()), null
        ).toFile();
        file.deleteOnExit();
        // Get handle for temporary file
        final WinNT.HANDLE handle = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile(
            file.getAbsolutePath(),
            Kernel32.GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            null,
            Kernel32.CREATE_ALWAYS,
            Kernel32.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            null
        );
        assert handle != WinBase.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        // Save original STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        final WinNT.HANDLE origin = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetStdHandle(Kernel32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        // Redirect STD_INPUT_HANDLE to the file handle
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.SetStdHandle(Kernel32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, handle);
        // Make your system call
        WriteFileFunctionCall.make();
        // Redirect original STD_INPUT_HANDLE back
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.SetStdHandle(Kernel32.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, origin);
        // Close temporary file handle
        Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(handle)
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(
            new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())), 
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            ),
            Matchers.equalTo("Hello, world")
        );
    }
}

Now it should work
